# Can I use きれいそう to say that someone looks beautiful?

Tags: grammar

Since きれいそう means "to look(seem) beautiful/clean" would it be okay if I used "彼女はきれいそうです" to say that a girl looks beautiful or should I just say "彼女はきれいです"?

Comment: It depends on the context.  Do you understand the difference between the two ～そう's (and also ～よう)?

Comment: Related or dup https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48984/45489

Comment: きれいそう can be used only before directly seeing her.